# Maximum number of pointers?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

Each Pointer is identified with a `[PointerPoint.PointerId][1]`. Is there a maximum number of pointers supported by WinRT or is this hugely device dependent?

Comment: What do you mean? What are you trying to do? There shouldn't be more than a few defined.

Comment: Hi @WiredPrairie what do you mean by a few? 16? 32? :D

Comment: A mouse, the touch support, trackpad, pen/stylus.

Comment: As far as I know, this'll give you the currently used pointers, some examples: mouse click - 1, touch tap - 1, touch pinch zoom - 2 (each finger is a pointer).

Answer (score 1):

It is device dependant. There are readily available monitors with 30 simultaneous contact points.

You can query the number of points on a specific device from the PointerDevice.MaxContacts property. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.pointerdevice.maxcontacts.aspx